# Convert a multidimensional array to a data frame Python

Tags: arrays, dataframe, unique, combinations

I have a data set as below:

```
data={ 'StoreID':['a','b','c','d'],
       'Sales':[1000,200,500,800],
       'Profit':[600,100,300,500]
}
data=pd.DataFrame(data)
data.set_index(['StoreID'],inplace=True,drop=True)
X=data.values
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
dist=euclidean_distances(X)
```

Now I get an array as below:

```
array([[0. ,943,583,223],
       [943, 0.,360,721],
       [583,360,0., 360],
       [223,721,360, 0.]])
```

My purpose to get unique combinations of stores and their corresponding distance. I would like the end results  as a data frame below:

```
Store   NextStore   Dist
a       b           943
a       c           583
a       d           223
b       c           360
b       d           721
c       d           360
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want [pandas.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) which will "unpivot" the distance matrix into tall-and-skinny format.

```
m = pd.DataFrame(dist)
m.columns = list('abcd')
m['Store'] = list('abcd')
```

...which produces:

```
            a           b           c           d Store
0    0.000000  943.398113  583.095189  223.606798     a
1  943.398113    0.000000  360.555128  721.110255     b
2  583.095189  360.555128    0.000000  360.555128     c
3  223.606798  721.110255  360.555128    0.000000     d
```

Melt data into tall-and-skinny format:

```
pd.melt(m, id_vars=['Store'], var_name='nextStore')

   Store nextStore       value
0      a         a    0.000000
1      b         a  943.398113
2      c         a  583.095189
3      d         a  223.606798
4      a         b  943.398113
5      b         b    0.000000
6      c         b  360.555128
7      d         b  721.110255
8      a         c  583.095189
9      b         c  360.555128
10     c         c    0.000000
11     d         c  360.555128
12     a         d  223.606798
13     b         d  721.110255
14     c         d  360.555128
15     d         d    0.000000
```

Remove redundant rows, convert dist to int, and sort:

```
df2 = pd.melt(m, id_vars=['Store'], 
                 var_name='NextStore',
                 value_name='Dist')
df3 =  df2[df2.Store < df2.NextStore].copy()
df3.Dist = df3.Dist.astype('int')
df3.sort_values(by=['Store', 'NextStore'])

   Store NextStore  Dist
4      a         b   943
8      a         c   583
12     a         d   223
9      b         c   360
13     b         d   721
14     c         d   360
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a 2D array with shape (14576, 24) respectively elements and the number of features that are going to constitute my dataframe.

```
data_from_2Darray = {}

for i in range(name_2Darray.shape[1]):

         data_from_2Darray["df_column_name{}".format(i)] = name_2Darray[:,i]


#visualize the result
pd.DataFrame(data=data_from_2Darray).plot()

#the converted array in dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data_from_2Darray)
```